# Hide Products from a specific category in the Product Grid Magento

Tags: php, magento

I am creating a website that sells custom gift baskets. I've created a module that automatically creates a new configurable product every time the user creates a new gift basket. The module assigns the product to the category "Customer generated", before it adds the gift basket to the cart.

My dilemma now is how do I prevent the products from the "Customer generated" category from showing on the Products grid. I have started on a module that modifies the *_prepareCollection()* function but I can't quite figure out how I can hide the products from that one specific category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that those new products have a specific attribute (for example sku) you can filter them out. Let's say all the custom products have the sku starting with 'custom_conf_' than you can apply a filter to your collection inside the *_prepareCollection* function like this:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('nlike' => 'custom_conf_%'));
```

You can apply the filter using any attribute that it's different from the rest of your products.

Comment: The way it works is there are already default products (gift baskets) created with a fixed SKU and these default products become the basis for the custom created gift baskets. The SKUs for the dynamically created products are a combination of the default product SKU + a hash, so the method suggested would also hide the default products together with the custom created products.

Comment: I didn't suggest using the SKU. It was only an example. In case you have no way of determining which are the custom created products and which are the original ones I suggest you create a new "yes/no" attribute (for example 'is_custom'), add it to your set and when generating the custom products mark them as yes like this $product->setIsCustom(1). Now you'll have a way to identify those products and filter the collection like this $collection->addAttributeToFilter('is_custom', array('eq' => 1));

Comment: I tried using the method and it works like a charm. I didn't have to load the categories for the custom products. Thanks for the help.